# Deployed SSIS package will not read a file

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, ssms, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package that is supposed to read a folder and if the folder contains any text files, it will read them and store the data into a database. The package works flawlessly from the file system, however when I deployed it it fails.
The package uses a project level variable that remains consistent that acts as a folder path to see which folder to look in for files.

The SQL Server Agent gives me this error:
[image]
After looking at the execution report I see following error messages if I execute it with the service account through SQL Server Agent:
"The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters"

"The file name '(path here)' specified in the connection was not valid"

"The Flat File Connection manager failed validation"
[image]
However, if I run it myself by directly right clicking on the package in the catalog and executing, the execution report will come back as successful but it will contain a warning that says: "Read Files From File Input Folder Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty"
[image]

I suspect it is a permissions error, but I haven't dealt much with the permissions in Microsoft SQL Server and the service account that I am using was not created by me. I have tried changing the security of both package and project from the default "Encrypt sensitive data with user key" to "Do not save sensitive data", rebuilding and redeploying but that didn't help at all.
It is most likely a permissions error but I've  been puzzled on how to go about it. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: After setting the "Delay Validation" on tasks in the control flow and executing the package with SQL Server Agent it now comes back with 2 less errors
[image]

Comment: Have you set the SSIS property DelayValidation to true on Tasks and Connection Managers? Try that.

Comment: @GabrielVa I have set the DelayValidation to true on all tasks in control flow and I managed to get rid of 2 errors when executing with SQL Agent. See updated tail end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For filesystem task to work the executing account need permission to the folder in question. When you execute the package via the SQL-agent the package is executed under the account running the SQL-agent account, when you right click the package and press execute the package is executed as your account.

One problem could be that the SQL-agent account doesn't have permission to the folder, and can't enumerate the content. You can verify this by changing the SQL-server account to your own account temporary and running the job again:

- Open Sql Server Configuraiton Manager
- Under `SQL Server Services` double click `SQL Server Aggent`
- Change the account to your own account
- Restart the service

If this resolvs the problem, change back to the SQL-server account and check the folder permissions on the folder you are trying to enumerate. Add the SQL-agent account or group the account is included in to have permission to read the folder. Obviously you can also just check the folder permissions to begin with, and make sure the executing account have permission to it.